# Error when running the command "rake build"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake

I wanted to build my gem by running **rake build** but I got this error after running the said command:

```
cathy:trunk catherine$ rake build --trace
** Invoke build (first_time)
** Execute build
rake aborted!
WARNING:  no homepage specified
WARNING:  description and summary are identical
WARNING:  open-ended dependency on rake (>= 0, development) is not recommended
  if rake is semantically versioned, use:
    add_development_dependency 'rake', '~> 0'
WARNING:  open-ended dependency on si_common (>= 0, development) is not recommended
  if si_common is semantically versioned, use:
    add_development_dependency 'si_common', '~> 0'
WARNING:  See http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ for help
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `bytesize' for nil:NilClass
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:149:in `sh'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:57:in `build_gem'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/bundler-1.7.8/lib/bundler/gem_helper.rb:39:in `block in install'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/catherine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => build
cathy:trunk catherine$
```

What could be the issue here? Could it be because of the version of some of my gems? If it is, what can I possibly do to be able to build my gem successfully?

I am currently using **ruby 2.0.0p259** (2014-11-13 revision 48408) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0] and **rails 3.2.20**

Actually, I was able to do this before (building my gem and installing it on my local machine) but I think I did a bundle update that's why it doesn't work anymore. Thought I am not 100% sure if it's really the cause.

Comment: Would you mind to share a gemspec?

Comment: I would try to update the bundler gem (`gem update bundler`), because the version 1.7.8 is quite outdated

Comment: Hi @mudasobwa, I can do a build now. I might have accidentally removed some file/s that is/are not tracked because I was able to build from a new clone of my repository. Thanks anyway. :)